# UITableViewCell with Checkmark, duplicating checkmarks

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

So far search on Stack Overflow I havent found a situation that is like mine. Any assistance is greatly appreciated: I keep seeing that if I put a checkmark on Person A, Person H will also have one as well as does a person about 10 away. Basically abut every 10 it repeats a check mark.

Here is my code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

             }

cell.textLabel.text = 

[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[myArrayOfAddressBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"FirstName"],[[myArrayOfAddressBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"LastName"]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = 

[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[myArrayOfAddressBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Address"]];

return cell;
```

}

In my did select row for index path I have this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];

if ([[myArrayOfAddressBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"emailSelected"] != @"YES")
{    
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
[[myArrayOfAddressBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"emailSelected"];
}
else
{    
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [[myArrayOfAddressBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"emailSelected"];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to how `UITableView` "recycles" `UITableViewCell` for efficiency purposes, and how you are marking your cells when they are selected.

You need to refresh/set the `accessoryType` value for every cell you process/create within `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You properly update the state in your `myArrayOfAddressBooks` data structure, and you just need to use this information in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *info = [myArrayOfAddressBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [info objectForKey:@"FirstName"],[info objectForKey:@"LastName"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@", [info objectForKey:@"Address"]];

    cell.accessoryType = ([[info objectForKey:@"emailSelected"] isEqualString:@"YES"]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Also, unless there is a good reason for saving the state as `@"Yes"` or `@"No"` strings, why not save them as `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` or `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]`? This will simplify your logic when you want to do comparisons versus having to use `isEqualToString:` all the time.

e.g.

```
    cell.accessoryType = ([[info objectForKey:@"emailSelected"] boolValue]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```