# Save button not working properly when saving & retrieving data from NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

I've issue with save button's functionality.

When I am using small numbers(less than 10) of data(rows) in my `UITableView`, it works perfectly. but when I used same function on large number(more than 260) of data(rows) in `UITableView` and click at save button in any row's index while pressing button to show it as selected that row but it also showing some other rows as selected as well as with that specific pressed button's row,
Here is my code.

So please do let me know where I am wrong? & how to do it in right way?

**In .h file I've defined**

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myFavorites;
```

**in .m file I've defined following code first of all in `viewDidLoad` for `NSUserDefault`**

```
 myFavorites = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mutableArray"] mutableCopy]];
```

and in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I've defined following to display Favorite Button

```
UIButton *addtoFavsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

if([myFavorites containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.row]]) {

    [addtoFavsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}else{
    [addtoFavsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    addtoFavsButton.selected=!addtoFavsButton.selected;

}
addtoFavsButton.frame = CGRectMake(370.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 45.0f);

[cell addSubview:addtoFavsButton];
[addtoFavsButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(addtoFavs:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:addtoFavsButton];
[addtoFavsButton setTag:indexPath.row];
```

And Finally here goes Favorite buttons Function.

```
- (IBAction)addtoFavs: (id)sender
{

    UIButton *addtoFavsButton = sender;

    //NSLog(@"selected favourite button tag %li", (long)addtoFavsButton.tag);
    NSNumber * mynumber = @(addtoFavsButton.tag);
   // NSLog (@"number is %@", mynumber);
    addtoFavsButton.selected=!addtoFavsButton.selected;


    if (addtoFavsButton.selected) {
        [addtoFavsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [myFavorites removeObject:mynumber];

    }
    else{

        [addtoFavsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if(myFavorites == nil){
            myFavorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [myFavorites addObject:mynumber];
        }
        else{
            [myFavorites addObject:mynumber];
        }

    }

    //NSLog(@"My array: %@", myFavorites);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myFavorites forKey:@"mutableArray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

   // NSLog(@"Saved Array: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mutableArray"]);

    //  addtoFavsButton.selected=!addtoFavsButton.selected;


}
```

So please let me know when I used small amount of data in my tableview such as less than 10 rows it works perfectly but when I used to input large amount of data like as more than 260 rows and select favorite button it also used to select more than one row's favorite button randomly, also when i used to deselect that very first selected button it also keep showing me selected image but removes object from NSUserDefault.

Please suggest me where I am doing it wrong. . .

Thanks.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556590/uitableviewcell-with-checkmark-duplicating-checkmarks

Comment: can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method code ?

Comment: @CodeChanger ya sure, let me edit my question once agian.  and to put complete functionality of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You should really just use a custom cell class. This allows you to separate UI and business logic.

You can use the class to relay when a button has been tapped on the cell, sending a message back through the delegate.

`FavoritesCellDelegate`: Delegate to be implemented by UIViewController

```
@protocol FavoritesCellDelegate<NSObject>
- (void)favoritesCellButtonTapped:(FavoritesCell *)cell;
@end
```

`FavoritesCell`: Customize UI in here

```
- (IBAction)favButtonTapped:(UIButton *)favButton
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(favoritesCellButtonTapped:)])
    {
        [self.delegate favoritesCellButtonTapped:self];
    }
}
```

`UIViewController <FavoritesCellDelegate>`: UIViewController that handles updating user defaults values

```
- (void)favoritesCellButtonTapped:(FavoritesCell *)cell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathforCell:cell];
    // Get item from datasource using indexPath
    // Update user defaults with value from cell for item
}
```

Comment: custom cell class is not good option, coz I am already using standard cell, and there are too many functionality that I've related with that standard cell... so I am not able to think about custom cell class at this point.

Comment: A custom cell class is certainly a good option, considering you're programmatically creating a button in the `cellForRow` then adding it without constraints. Have you considered that that it might not look right on all device sizes? You also aren't showing whether or not you are using `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

did you have set like this ? reuse. When you have 260 cells , if cell would not recycle, it will be Consumption much performance. At the same time, when you click first cell button, it maybe let third button or other button have been selected.

Comment: Suggest a custom cell is better.